# awk script: check if all words(fields) from one file are contained in another file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, compare

I am new to awk scripting.
I want to do a field by word (field) comparison of two files File1.txt and File2.txt. 
The files contain a list of | (pipe) separated field.

```
    File 1:
    -------------------
    aaa|bbb|ccc|eee|fff
    lll|mmm|nnn|ooo|ppp
    rrr|sss|ttt|uuu|vvv

    File 2: 
    -------------------
    aaa|bbb|ccc|eee|fff
    rrr|sss|ttt|uuu|vvv
    rrr|sss|ttt|uuu|uuu
```

We compare the same line no. in both the files.

Fields in Line 1 of both file match.

In Line 2 all the fields (lll, mmm, nnn, ooo, ppp)  donot not match with all fields (rrr, sss, ttt, uuu, vvv) in line 2 of File 2. Similarly the 5th field (vvv, uuu) of 3rd line in both the files donot match.

Hence Line no. 2 and Line no. 3 should get echoed by bash.

Both files will follow an order.

Answer (score 2):

this line should do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}a[FNR]!=$0' file1 file2
```

output:

```
rrr|sss|ttt|uuu|vvv
rrr|sss|ttt|uuu|uuu
```

Answer (score 1):

Two compare two files, better use already inbuilt command sdiff:

```
 sdiff File1 File2
```

This will display the lines which differ in both files.

Doing with awk.

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print $0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: thanks, but this will compare two lines instead of a field in each line.

Comment: the awk one-liner will compare line#2 in file2 to line#1 in file1. not OP wanted.`We compare the same line no. in both the files.`

Comment: thanks I want a similar thing, but I also want to compare field by field in each line. So in case a field does not match I can say which field does not match.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines may be adapted following needs, another language like perl may be more appropriate

```
i=1
while read -r -u4 l1 || read -r -u5 l2; do
  if [[ $l1 != $l2 ]]; then
    echo "$i: $l1 != $l2"
  fi
  ((i+=1))
done 4<file1 5<file2
```