# List strings which are not found in a text file

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, awk, sed

I have a directory with hundreds of files in it. The names of all the files that are in the directory are also listed in a Javascript file (see below). I want to find the names of the files in the directory which are **not present** in the text file. Example:

```
% ls ./images/ 
a.png
c.png
x.png
```

File:

```
{
   name: "A",
   filename: "a.png"

},
{
   name: "X",
   filename: "x.png"

}
```

In this case the output should be "`c.png`".

I found some `awk` scripts which are able find the string (see: [awk script: check if all words(fields) from one file are contained in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945691/awk-script-check-if-all-wordsfields-from-one-file-are-contained-in-another-fi)).  However in my case I want to find the list of files which *do not* match.

Comment: Are you sure the input file isn't JSON? If it is, `name` and `filename` should be double quoted.

Comment: If it's JSON, then it's definitely something to run through a JSON parser. If it's not, someone needs a poke for making something that looks like JSON that isn't. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be accomplished by the following command

```
$ mawk '/filename:/{gsub("\"","",$2);names[$2]}
        END{while(("ls ?.png"|getline fnm)>0){
               if(!(fnm in names)) print fnm
        }}' file.dat
```

In the first line we scan the data file, looking for the string `"filename"`, stripping the file name from quotes and eventually saving the filename in an array.

At the `END` we make a loop on the output of the pertinent `ls` command and if the current file name wasn't saved in the array we print it to stdout.

The tough part was to get the correct syntax for the final for loop...

---

*Addendum*

Following up the comment from the original poster, here it is a
modified version of the script

```
$ mawk '/filename:/{gsub("\"","",$2);names[$2]}
        END{while(("ls /var/www/html/img/*.png"|getline path)>0){
                n = split(path, parts, "/")
                fnm = parts[n]
                if(!(fnm in names)) print fnm
        }}' file.dat
```

that works for a fixed directory name. If the directory name must be
given at runtime, try the following

```
 $ extra_png () {
 mawk '/filename:/{gsub("\"","",$2);names[$2]}
        END{while(("ls '"$2"'/*.png"|getline path)>0){
                n = split(path, parts, "/")
                fnm = parts[n]
                if(!(fnm in names)) print fnm
        }}' "$1"
 }
 $ extra_png data.txt /var/www/html/img
 c.png
 $
```

where the first command defines a shell function that accepts as
arguments a data file and a directory to scan.

As a side note, this `awk` script find the png files not mentioned in
the data file (as per the OP request), it may be interesting to know
if filenames mentioned in the file are not present in the
directory. But this could be the subject of another question.

Comment: the image files are in some other directory. `ls /var/www/html/img/*` and when i do this it list all the files.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    while (ARGC > 2) {
        sub(/.*\//,"",ARGV[--ARGC])
        targets[ARGV[ARGC]]
        delete ARGV[ARGC]
    }
}
sub(/.*filename:[[:space:]]*"/,"") && sub(/\"[[:space:]]*$/,"") {
    present[$0]
}
END {
    print "Present:"
    for (file in present) {
        if (file in targets) {
            print "\t" file
        }
    }

    print "\nAbsent:"
    for (file in targets) {
        if (! (file in present) ) {
            print "\t" file
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file image/*
Present:
        x.png
        a.png

Absent:
        c.png
```

Note that this will work no matter what characters your file names contain, including spaces and double quotes and does not attempt to parse the output of `ls` which is always a bad idea.

Comment: Looks like all the files are listed in the absent section. The text file contains only the filenames with path-names not included. Ex: `x.png and not /var/www/img/x.png`

Comment: OK, but why are you mentioning it? The script does what you wanted, right?

Comment: oh i meant these files are actually present in the data file. They need to be shown in the present section. The script doesnt work.

Comment: What are you trying to tell us? The script checks whether files in an `image` directory exist in a given file exactly as you asked for. In what way does the script "not work"? Edit your question to clarify if there is a misunderstanding of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you can install some cool modules from [CPAN](https://metacpan.org), I propose a bit cleaner (IMHO) script for your quest:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.010; 
use JSON;
use Path::Tiny;

my $json_data = path('images.json')->slurp;
my $data = decode_json( $json_data );

my %files_to_check = map { $_->basename => 0 } path('images')->children; 
my @files_in_json = map { $_->{filename} } @$data; 
delete @files_to_check{ @files_in_json }; # delete all files we have in JSON

say "$_" for sort keys %files_to_check;
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have the idea that you must find or not find something in a list, think *hashes*. A hash is a quick way to index a list since you can find whether something or not is in a list by simply looking at the key.

In the first half of this program, I am going through your JSON file looking for the file names and storing them in a hash called `%files`. In the second half, I go through the directory where my `png` files are located and check to see if each one is in that `%files` hash. If a particular entry doesn't exist, I know that it's not in my JSON file.

> **NOTE:** I could have used `use JSON;` to parse my JSON file. However, in this demonstration, I am merely looking for `filename` lines to keep things simple. If this was an actual program, use the `JSON` module.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    FILE_NAME       => 'file.txt',
    DIR_NAME        => 'temp',
};

#
# Build the %files hash
#
open my $fh, "<", FILE_NAME;
my %files;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { 
    chomp $line;
    next unless $line =~ /\s+filename:\s+"(.+)"/;
    my $file = $1;
    $files{$file} = 1;
}
close $fh;

#
# Go through directory looking for entries not in %files
#
opendir my $dh, DIR_NAME;
while ( my $file = readdir $dh ) {
    next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";
    if ( not exists $files{$file} ) {
        say qq(File "$file" not in list);
    }
}
closedir $dh;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to list files that are in your data file but that are missing from your directory listing using Perl is to use a file test *in the directory*  (or pass the full path) that prints the file's name "if file does not exist" or "unless file does exist":

```
perl -nE 'map { say if !-e $_ } m/\"(.*)\"/ if /filename/' data.js
```

**or** to do the opposite (your example) - *i.e.* to print a file name (`$fname`) from a directory listing if it can't be found in an array of names (`@m`) created from  your file list data (`data.js`):

```
perl -nE 'push @m, m/\"(.*)\"/ if /filename/ }{ 
         for $fname (glob "*"){ say $fname if !grep { $_ eq $fname } @m}' data.js
```

---

Here is a full script variation on what @neuhaus posted. The difference is the following approach uses [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/release/IO-All) to create an IO "object" from the directory `'./images/'` as a hash and then lists the names of the files with `keys`. I modified the data in your text file to illustrate the `grep unless` statement:

```
# files.pl
use IO::All;
@files =  keys %{ io('./images/') }  ;

while(<DATA>) {
  push @flist, m/\"(.*)\"/ if /filename/  ; 
}

for $fname ( @flist) {print $fname unless grep { $_ eq $name } @files}  ;

__DATA__

{
   name: "A",
   filename: "a.png"
},
   {
   name: "X",
   filename: "x.png"
},
  {
   name: "Z",
   filename: "z.png"
}
```

**output** (if `perl files.pl` is run in a directory containing the `./images/` directory):

```
  % ls ./images/ 
  a.png x.png y.png z.png
  % perl files.pl
  y.png
```

In the `__DATA__` section (standing in for the `data.js` file) file names are extracted into `@files`. Files that are in the directory listing are printed `unless` they are can be found with `grep` in `@files`.

Here it is a version as a one liner with your data in `data.js`:

```
perl -MIO::All -lne 'push @flist, m/\"(.*)\"/ if /filename/ ; 
   }{ for $name (keys %{ io "./images/" }){ print $name 
   unless grep { $_ eq $name } @flist }' data.js
```

A more Unix-ish approach might use `glob` from inside the `/images/` directory (caveat: there are sometimes issues concerning file names with spaces on certain platforms):

```
 perl -MIO::All -lne  'push @flist, m/\"(.*)\"/ if /filename/ ; 
    }{ for $name ( glob("*.png") ){ print $name 
    unless grep { $_ eq $name } @flist }' data.js
```

or file and directory handles with [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html)

```
... 
opendir(my $dir, ".") || die; 
@files = readdir $dir ;
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution in perl:

`@list` is the array with the filenames.

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt");
my $contents = do { local $/ = <$fh> };
my $string = <$fh>;
close($fh);

foreach my $entry (@list) {
    print "$entry is not in file\n" if index($contents, $entry) == -1;
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to suggest ways for populating @list.